# How do I get the path of a view from my business layer assembly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, io

I am trying to read the contents of a view into a string variable like so -

`string _template = File.ReadAllText(@"Views/emails/registrationconfirmation.cshtml");`

This is so it can be used with [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) to create an email from the template.

This code is in my business layer assembly. I think I need the physical path instead of the virtual path I am trying to use.

The file is in the `Views/emails` folder of my MVC3 project. How do I programatically get the correct path I need to read the file?

Comment: Have you evaluated ActionMailer.NET?  It's worth a look and can be installed via NuGet.  https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home

Comment: Thanks, I am going to look into the standalone version of this. Also actually I read that it uses RazorEngine which is interesting. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You business layer shouldn't be trying to get paths to views. If it needs to work with such paths, they should be passed as argument from the UI layer.

So in your business layer instead of having this:

```
public class MyBusiness : IMyBusiness
{
    public string RenderView()
    {
        string _template = File.ReadAllText(@"Views/emails/registrationconfirmation.cshtml");
        ...
    }
}
```

you could have this:

```
public class MyBusiness
{
    public string RenderView(string viewPath)
    {
        string _template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);
        ...
    }
}
```

It's now the responsibility of the calling code situated in your controller that will take care of passing the proper path (which in the case of an ASP.NET application could be obtained using the `Server.MapPath` function and in the case of a desktop application could be a relative path and so on). This way your business layer is no longer strongly coupled to ASP.NET.

Another possibility is to have the business layer take the base physical path of your application as constructor argument:

```
public class MyBusiness : IMyBusiness
{
    private readonly string _basePath;
    public MyBusiness(string basePath)
    {
        _basePath = basePath;
    }

    public string RenderView()
    {
        var file = Path.Combine(_basePath, @"Views\emails\registrationconfirmation.cshtml");
        string _template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);
        ...
    }
}
```

and then all that's left is to configure your DI framework to pass the [`HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) property value when instantiating your business layer.

---

UPDATE: As @jgauffin pointed out in the comments section this code could be further improved by passing a `Stream` or a `StreamReader` to the business layer so that it doesn't even depend on a file. This will make it even easier to reuse and unit test in complete isolation.

Comment: I would rather pass a `Stream` to the business layer.

Comment: @jgauffin, yeah a `Stream`, what a great idea. This way the business layer code doesn't even depend on a file and could be easily unit tested in isolation. I will update my post to take this into account.

Comment: @Darin, thank you for both of these techniques. One question, If I were to pass a `Stream`, would that effectively be just passing a reference or does the whole stream get copied? Thanks,

Comment: A Stream is always a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) work for your case?

Comment: I don't think it does. The `Server` object doesn't seem to be available in the business layer assembly. I don't think it works outside of MVC application assembly. Thanks though.